# How does Html.ActionLinkMaxLengthQTip work?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I googled the exact phrase Html.ActionLinkMaxLengthQTip and not much came up?
What does this do? where can i see an example?

```
<%: Html.ActionLinkMaxLengthQTip(Html.Resource(Resources.Global.Button.Create), "StepType", "Create", "Training")%>
```

i also found this:

```
   <%: Html.GetQTipFor(model => model.End) %>
```

I also googled the exact phrase and came up with nothing

from the code i have i cannot figure out what this is doing.
any help?
thanks

Comment: where did you come across this?

Comment: in code i am working on. is this the same thing as a tooltip??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comment I would propose this is a custom extension specific to your application.

If you do a find all within your solution (probably in your `App_Code`) you should find where this html extension is defined and you should be able to see what it is doing.

Comment: i did search the whole solution and cannot find where it is declared. ill check app_code quick, thanks

Comment: where in the solution do i find app_code? i do not see it, sorry

Comment: App_Code would be a folder within the root of your mvc project.  Did you do a find all across the entire solution?

Comment: yes i did find all in ENTIRE solution :) and it does not show definition in the results and also I have an App_Browsers and App_Data folders, im confused :)

Comment: did it not even find the example you gave about?  have you got resharper installed?  can you click ctrl + b (go to declaration).